# QUERY for two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to use one query to search in two nonconsecutive columns.
So far I have the below formula.

`=QUERY(combine!A1:D,"SELECT * WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE LOWER("""&B1&""") or SELECT * WHERE LOWER(D) LIKE LOWER("""&B1&""")",1)`

But I want to type in `B1` different names that might be in column A or column D and there might be more than 20 rows with that name.

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT` and `WHERE` keywords should be included only once.

Try

`=QUERY(combine!A1:D,"SELECT * WHERE LOWER(A) LIKE LOWER("""&B1&""") or LOWER(D) LIKE LOWER("""&B1&""")",1)`